# Where does the Windows 7 taskbar store its data?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

Where does the Windows 7 taskbar store its data?

I'm aware of `c:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar` for pinned applications, but what I would like to do is for example add some pinned pages to [IE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_explorer) like I can do with Frequent pages.

I do hope it's not in the registry...

Comment: BTW: you get bad karma for answers like: registry or binary files.

Comment: you get bad karma for threatening comments...

Comment: Why the down votes???

Comment: down votes->even more bad karma

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Most of the data is stored in the registry under here, but it's not easily editable.

> `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\`