# How does windows store taskbar items?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, windows-registry, taskbar

In a question pertaining to windows 7, back from 2009 [@Mikeon asks](https://superuser.com/q/38617/1210194) where windows stores taskbar data.
He mentions the filepath `%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar`, which I opened in file explorer. It looks like a regular folder full or shortcuts, almost like the desktop.

I have fe set to sort by date by default, and I switched the sorting methods, but it never ended up in the same order as my taskbar. So I partially understand where it stores items, but how does it keep the order? Well duh, in the registry. [This answer](https://superuser.com/a/38625/1210194) shows where `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\`. I poked around here. There's many more folders to dig through, and I never found exactly where taskbar data was.

Even still, how is it formatted? My brain works in an sql/json oriented way, so this is a hard concept to grasp.

Out of curiosity, I added a text file to the folder previously mentioned just to see if it would show up on my taskbar. It didn't. I restarted my computer and still nothing. Seems to be shortcuts only. Just the thought of using the taskbar to store files sounds cool though!

Recap:
Where are the registry files?
How are they formatted?
*What do they taste like?*

Comment: This is likely what you are looking for:   https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration//configure-windows-10-taskbar  It is an XML file

Comment: @John, very neat. But isn't that just an administrator tool? It doesn't seem to be a file that exists on windows by default.

Comment: That is all that I could find on this subject.  There is not a great deal of easy to find information.